# Duplicate paths in react-route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In heder there is a component with live search in which there are links for the found film or TV series depending on what came from the server.

```
Use react-route v4
```

urlRusLat - just a function that returns translate name a movie

```
<div>
  <Helmet>
    <title>Movie-search</title>
  </Helmet>
  <Nav/>
  <Header/>

  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route exact path="/movie/:urlRusLat" component={Movie} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

and link in the search result

```
<Link to={item.media_type + '/' + urlRusLat(item.title || item.name) + '-' + item.id} className="result-element" key={index}>
```

and when I'm on the page of the movie and choose something from the search, then my path becoming like this

```
/movie/some-movie/movie/some-movie
```

how do that, when I click on the link in /move/some-movie

```
/movie/some-movie
```

how not to duplicate paths?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda how not to duplicate paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<Link to={'/' + item.media_type + '/' + urlRusLat(item.title || item.name) + '-' + item.id} className="result-element" key={index}>
```

Comment: Hi sir, that is urlRusLat?

Answer (score 4):

Just don't forget to add the `/` add the beginning of the route

```
 <NavLink activeClassName="activePage" to="/something/new/">Create Participants</NavLink>
```